# Looking for full-featured Web-Application theme sets similar to Pilu's web-app-theme

Tags: web-applications, templates

We develop a fair number of web-based applications, most of which are hosted on enterprise servers, and not accessible via the internet.

We haven't yet adapted a standard template for our web apps, and we waste a lot of time doing design work when we release an app that is consumed via a browser. I say waste because most of our applications are dead simple, and none of us are highly practiced designers. Doing the GUI work tends to waste developer time because they aren't as well seasoned in CSS as they are at their respective programming languages. Not surprisingly, we also end up with less-than-glamorous interfaces...

I want to find a good web application template and customise it to our corporate colours etc.

I have been looking at Pilu's web app theme and it looks great:

http://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme

Does anyone know of any other free or commercial packages along the same lines? I want to do a full investigation before we invest time in customisation.  Also, something targeting the Java world would be nice. I notice that pilu's web-app-theme has some cool Rails generators, but we mainly work with JSF.  This isn't really essential though - we mainly want to write our own HTML and it would be good if the documentation was sufficient that we could work backwards from a design concept to a finished product without too much trial and error guess work.

Thanks for your contributions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themeforest has some great (and cheap) themes that can take you quite far. Check out their admin skins here...

[ThemeForest Admin Skins](http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-skins)

Comment: i think the correct link is http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates