# CSS layout theme like Molio, Pilu’s web-app-theme or Yui App Theme?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, themes

I am looking for css layout theme similar to Molio, Pilu’s web-app-theme or Yui App Theme. Anyone got any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Found this link on a similar question

> http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-skins

Link to related SO question:

> [Looking for full-featured Web-Application theme sets similar to Pilu's web-app-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552149/looking-for-full-featured-web-application-theme-sets-similar-to-pilus-web-app-th)